# Engine sounds in racing computer games

Tags: audio

Always wanted to know, how these fancy [engine sounds](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NQYGqKHn92c) come into being.

Is it generated on the fly? If so, how do all these little quirks appear there (like intercooler sound)? Or is it pre-recorded, and if so, how does its pitch changes?

Comment: A lot of things in game development are exactly as you think they are. Lots of microphones, careful mounting, and simple pitch shifting for where you don't have samples (available even in [OpenAL](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Documentation/OpenAL%201.1%20Specification.htm#_4.3.2._Source_Attributes) (SOURCE_PITCH)) would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds are recorded using real cars on closed racetracks.  Games have huge development budgets, often topping $10 mil.  There's a reason for this.

Comment: 1. annectodical references from friends and collegues.

2. gamasutra.com, a game developers site that has tons of post-mortems and articles on how games are developed.

3. a show I once saw on how forza was developed

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine they would just record a car's sound and map it to its rpm, then the game just recalls the sound for whatever RPM the car is running at.  They would just have to have enough different sounds to make the pitch change between RPM unnoticeable.

Comment: Simulating the noise has been done but is complex. I went for recording in 250 rpm increments then fading between these over 200ms. Each 250rpm increment needs to be made incrementally louder. The pitch change is still noticable but not to bad.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post describing how this is done for Forza, for both engine noise & crashes:

http://jalopnik.com/5478591/inside-forza-motorsport-part-ii-making-the-cars-sound-awesome